# How fast / efficient is schematron validation?

Tags: xml, performance, validation, schematron

What are the **practical** limits of validating XML files using standard libraries and schematron expressions **in your experience**?

Are there some **numbers** available about how long an X MB / Y lines long file takes to validate using P language / Q library, and a set of Z schematron assertions?

As a very rough example, I am looking at e.g. XML input files up to 300 mB with c. 200,000 "records" per file, and (only estimated) 200 XML assertions to test per record, maybe 50% of which are more complex than just 0 or 1 co-occurence within the same "record".

Comment: That's a lot of variables to contend with.  Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: OK. How should I modify the question to make it work?

E.g. would you need example numbers? Or should I ask for freely available example files?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too broad to answer in general, but perhaps you'll find value in a single data point...

I've written Schematron that applies ~100 patterns against ~2,000 XSD files to check for conformance against design guidelines.  The checks complete and produce an HTML rendering of the results in about 37 seconds.  That time includes compilation of Schematron to XSLT and ant-based orchestration of the process.

This was achieved attending purely to functionality and maintainability of the code and so could probably be effectively optimized if faster execution were required.

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes - yes, absent any other answers that gave me a starting point, even one data point was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Schematron allows you to write very complex predicates to test against the instance document. The time it takes will depend almost entirely on the complexity of the rules you ask it to evaluate. Your question is therefore a bit like asking "how long will it take a C program to run" without giving any information about the program other than the fact that it's written in C.

Comment: I hesitate to respond to your answer with anything but "thanks", Mr. Kay :-)

I was just looking for an empirical way in to the problem area to save time actually running code purely for the sake of measuring it. Any tips like that would be most welcome. In German I would ask for "Erfahrungswerte".